# Passing multiple data in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel

I am using AngularJS. I would like to send multiple data in a HTTP post through AngularJS.I am using laravel php as backend and [tinymce](https://www.tinymce.com/) as my html text editor.The problem is that tinymce comes up with a model and i am unable to figure it out on how to pass data that is dealing with multiple models.

Here is my partial:

```
<div ng-controller="controller">

<div class="row">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-lg-8">
            <form role="form" method="post" >
                <div class="form-group" >
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" ng-model="post.title" placeholder="Type the title here">
                </div>

                <div action="" class="form-group" ng-controller="TinyMceController">
                    <textarea ui-tinymce="tinymceOptions" ng-model="tinymceModel" style="height:300px">

                    </textarea>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="" ng-model="post.tags" placeholder="Atleast one related tag">
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="postsave()">Submit</button>
                <button class="btn btn-default">Discard</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            RULES:
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

my controller:

```
app.controller('controller',['$scope','$rootScope','$http',function($scope,$rootScope,$http){

$scope.post={
    title:"",   
};


$scope.postsave= function(){
    $http({
        method:"POST",

        url:'http://localhost/../../...',
        data:        //I can pass title by using $scope.title but i aslo
                     //want to pass $scope.tinymcemodel


    })
    .success(function(result){
        alert(result);
    })
}
```

Any help would be great.Also suggest me if there is a better way of doing it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like your `post.tags` is structured, you should do the same. Put all your children under a parent and submit the parent. Let's look at that:

```
$scope.formData = {}; //parent
```

Then your textarea/title should be altered accordingly:

```
ng-model="formData.title" //child
ng-model="formData.tinymcemodel" //child
```

And then when you pass your data over, you can just pass `this.formData`.

```
$scope.postsave= function(){
    $http({
        method:"POST",
        url:'http://localhost/../../...',
        data: this.formData
    })
    .success(function(result){
        alert(result);
    })
};
```

This will properly send over the object to the server, which will have the key:value pairs as your `title` and `tinymcemodel`. Note that `post.tags` won't be included in this submission given that it belongs to another parent.